# Iterator of Vector of Vectors fails to work with a 1-D Vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

In my program, I have a vector of vector of ints. Now I want to take one vector from the vector of vectors and have it manipulated in another vector container, but I get the error...

```
|error: conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' requested|
```

An example of what I am trying to do is as follows....

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int> > k (13,5);

void some_funct() {
    vector<int> new_v (k[2].begin(), k[2].end());  //This line is what throws the error
    //here I do some stuff with new_v (e.g. sort it)
}
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I tried a couple of things like assigning the begin() and end() iterators to const iterator types... `vector<int>::const_iterator it = k[2].begin();`  but that didn't work either.

This should work (because k[x] would be a vector) but I don't know what is going wrong. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

After revision of my code, I noticed that there actually was an error. Instead of doing `vector<int> new_v (k[2].begin(),k[2].end());` I did `vector<int> new_v = (k[2].begin(),k[2].end());`.

I would like to thank **Rob** for giving me the initiative to copy and paste my code into SO, where I noticed my mistake.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't in the line above? Which should be, `std::vector<std::vector<int>> k(13, std::vector<int>(5));`?

Comment: Nope, my program is quite complex, there is tons of code between the two lines shown

Comment: In any case, `std::vector<int> new_v(k[2]);` should work just as well.

Comment: Nice! It works, but that still doesn't tell me why the preceding method doesn't work, hmmmmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to know, because you haven't posted your *actual* code into the question. I suspect that you mis-copied the code from your project into Stack Overflow.

The offending line in your project looks something like this:

```
vector<int> new_v = (k[2].begin(), k[2].end());
```

Note the extra `=`.

You are initializing `new_v` with an expression of type `vector::iterator`, which won't work. The statement you typed into SO, however, *will* work:

```
vector<int> new_v (k[2].begin(), k[2].end());
```

As will this:

```
vector<int> new_v = vector(k[2].begin(), k[2].end());
```

Or either of these:

```
vector<int> new_v(k[2]);
vector<int> new_v = k[2];
```

See https://ideone.com/uK8Xg and the corresponding error message.

Comment: You got the answer dead on! Good job!

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells us that you're trying to (re-)create a vector from a vector::iterator. since vector does not support this kind of constructor or copy assignment, the compiler would raise an error. However your posted code here is valid.